# jar package close without error log in linux server

Tags: java, linux, jar

There are package and log.I run package as `java -jar guandan-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &` comand.The procedure will close in about five minutes.And I found there not Error text in log

链接：https://pan.baidu.com/s/1qN95IUEYITRY4tGj6-Rjjg
提取码：e8jj

tell me what's wrong with this package

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).